# How do I transform [IO X] into IO [X]

Tags: haskell

I have some data type X and a function which returns IO [X] but my computation is currently returning [IO X]. 
What is a general method for transforming [IO X] into IO [X]?

Comment: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BIO+x%5D+-%3E+IO+%5Bx%5D

Comment: I wasn't aware hoogle could be used like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [sequence](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.18/base-4.11.1.0/Prelude.html#v:sequence).

E.g.

```
> sequence [return 1, return 2]
[1,2]
```

Comment: Yep, but also: better than `sequence` is `sequenceA` (more general, therefore a better habit to use it).

Comment: @GabrielL. I'd expect to see `sequence` be made a synonym of `sequenceA` at some point. Yeah, effectively there's no reason ever to use the `Monad`- instead of `Applicative`-constrained version, after the AMP.